# java.lang.ClassCastException on collect() of ArrayList<Document>

Tags: java, mongodb, casting, classcastexception, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to search through a mongo database to find a user given search term in one of the fields:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = {"/classes/search/{term}"})
    public String className (
        @PathVariable(required = true, value = "term") String term
    ) throws Exception {
        // Escape user input
        final String filteredTerm = escapeUserInput(term);

        // Match using Bson filter
        ArrayList<Document> matchedClasses = new ArrayList<Document>();
        for (String modName : DATABASE.listCollectionNames()) {
            ArrayList<Document> filteredContents = new ArrayList<Document>();
            try {
                getCollection(modName).find(
                    Filters.or(
                        Filters.text(filteredTerm),
                        Filters.eq("count", Long.parseLong(filteredTerm))
                    )
                ).into(filteredContents);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                getCollection(modName).find(Filters.text(filteredTerm)).into(filteredContents);
            }

            // Add to final doc if match is found
            if (filteredContents != null) {
                matchedClasses.addAll(filteredContents);
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(matchedClasses
            .stream()
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );

    }

}
```

*All `getCollection()` does is retrieve the mongo collection.*

When passing any search term that SUCCESSFULLY matches something in the database, I get a `ClassCastException` supposedly on Line 140 (`.collect(Collectors.toList())`)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bson.Document cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (org.bson.Document is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare(Comparators.java:47) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.end(DistinctOps.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at com.api.main.Executer.className(Executer.java:140) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
<TRUNCATED>
```

I suspect it's something to do with `Filters.text` as that is what I changed which has started to cause this error but I don't understand why and where my next step from here would be?

Comment: You are calling sorted on the stream of Document. If it doesn't implement Comparable, you should provide a custom comparator as the argument of sorted.

Comment: `String.valueOf(matchedClasses… `, you are trying to convert a list of objects to a string. I assume this isn’t supported and it begs the question, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matchedClasses` is an `ArrayList<Document>` and `Document` does not implement `Comparable`.

When running `.collect(Collectors.toList())`, it also tries to sort the `Stream` elements because you called `sorted`. Bot for sorting, the elements need to either implement `Comparable` or pass a `Comparator` to `.sorted()`.

As `Document` is a MongoDB class that you cannot control, you need to pass a `Compatator` to `.sorted()`:

```java
//...
.sorted((document1,document2)->/*compare documents here*/)
//...
```

Comment: That is confusing as I have a similar function above that collects a `ArrayList<Document>` and returns successfully

Comment: ```java
ArrayList<Document> dbContents = new ArrayList<Document>();
<TRUNCATED>        
return String.valueOf(dbContents
            .stream()
            .distinct()
            .map(typeDoc -> typeDoc.toJson())
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
```

Comment: Ah I see what I've done, I've been a silly goose.

I forgot to convert the `Document` objects to JSON strings like I had done with my other route using `.map(typeDoc -> typeDoc.toJson())` prior to using `sorted()`. Now resolved and will accept this answer as it basically implies the same logic.

Thanks for all the help :)